# Loop thats supposed to append data into separate text files for each API query I do, is duplicating the data across those separate files

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop

I have a list of websites that I'm doing an API query on. I also have a separate list that stores a shortened version of these websites which I want to be the name of the text file where the data is getting appended to from the API query.

What I want to do is for each website, append the data from the query into a file named website1.txt and so on and so forth. Instead whats happening is the all the data from website1,website2,website3 is getting appended to website1.txt,website2.txt etc. All these text files have the same data, instead of separate data being appended to each text files.

Heres my code:

```
list_of_websites = ['api.cats.com/animaldata', 'api.elephants.com/animaldata', 'api.dogs.com/animaldata']

name_of_websites = ['cats data', 'elephants data', 'dogs data']

for website in list_of_websites:
    
    
    counter = 1 
    while True:
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.superComputer.info?page={counter}", headers={ "Accept": "application/.v3+json", "Authorization": "Bearer 123456"}, params={"site": f"{website}"})
           
            
                
            
        
        if response.json():
            for site in name_of_websites:    
                file_name = f"{site}.txt"  
            
                f = open(file_name, "a") 
                
            
                f.write(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
            counter += 1

            
            
        else:
            break
```

Comment: add `print(f"https://api.superComputer.info?page={counter}")` to your loop

Comment: Did you want to see the results thats returned? Is that why you wanted me to add the print statement? Sorry, not understanding the context.

Comment: I want you to confirm that your url is properly formatted

Comment: can you please explain why the while loop is added? Also, what is expected to be the page values in the request URL? the index of the website in the lists?

Comment: @apoorvakamath The reason why I added the while loop is because I need to paginate through a large list of websites. The page value is just the number 1. I'm updating that counter each iteration.

Comment: @PaulH It returns https://api.superComputer.info?page=1&site:api.cats.com/animaldata I kind of reformatted the code, but the API I'm targeting lets me pass in websites as a parameter. The target API is an API that lets me access other API's if that make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is 1-1 mapping with websites urls and website names you can use zip and iterate over it.

And since all the content of different pages is to be appended to a single file you can open it just once outside the while loop.

```py
list_of_websites = ['api.cats.com/animaldata', 'api.elephants.com/animaldata', 'api.dogs.com/animaldata']

name_of_websites = ['cats data', 'elephants data', 'dogs data']

for website, website_name in zip(list_of_websites,name_of_websites):
    
    counter = 1
    file_name = f"{website_name}.txt"
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        while True:  
            response = requests.get("https://api.superComputer.info", headers={ "Accept": "application/.v3+json", "Authorization": "Bearer 123456"}, params={"page": counter, "site": f"{website}"})
            if response.ok:
                f.write(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
                counter +=1
            else:
                break
```

Comment: So I tried this method, but it looks like all the data is getting appended to a single file. I'm still experiencing the same issue as before. I wanted all the date for 'api.cats.com/animaldata' to be in its own text file and not include the data from the sites. I've learned new something about the zip function however :)

Comment: Logically the solution should work. Can you verify that the response is what you expect from each API call and the params are correctly sent for each call?
What is the response when the page number is unavailable are we correctly breaking out of the while loop? try moving the page number to params dictionary instead of having it in the url

Comment: Actually it works now! It's perfect. Can I ask why you placed the file_name before the while loop? Why not declare it inside the while loop?

Comment: @SuperDummy since you have to create 1 file per website, opening it multiple times inside the while loop for each page didn't make sense. If its outside the while loop, you open the file once and then keep writing into it for every page, and then once you are done with all the pages file is closed.

Comment: @apporva kamath Thank you! You are amazing. I hope the rest of your week is just as fantastic as mines will be now that you've helped me overcome this obstacle. :)

Comment: @SuperDummy I am happy that I could help you :)